# How to pass data (arrays) between functions

Tags: objective-c, arrays, s7graphview

I must use `s7graphview` library for draw simple histogram, and I've got custom function called 
`-(IBAction)histogram:(id)sender;`. in this function every pixel from image is passed to array as RGB representation. then pixels are counted and I've got red, green and blue array. I can send to NSLog or something but problem is, when I try to send 3 arrays to `- (NSArray *)graphView:(S7GraphView *)graphView yValuesForPlot:(NSUInteger)plotIndex;`. both functions are in the same .m file, and I have no idea how to pass data between them, because when I write redArray, Xcode don't suggest me this name.

Comment: Xcode doesn't always prompt you (correctly).  If this is your own function you can add more parameters for passing in more data.  (By the way, your post is virtually unintelligible -- your question is unclear at best.)

Comment: `- (NSArray *)graphView:(S7GraphView *)graphView yValuesForPlot:(NSUInteger)plotIndex;` isn't my function. it's delegate function.

Comment: You need to find a way to allow that delegate method to see your three arrays. Have you tried making your three arrays into ivars and accessing them from within that graphView delegate method?

Comment: If you wrote the code, you can have your implementation access, eg, properties that were set separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `- (NSArray *)graphView:(S7GraphView *)graphView yValuesForPlot:(NSUInteger)plotIndex` is a delegate method, it should be **implemented** in your class that is posing as a delegate to `S7GraphView` object. You don't call explicitly, you define it as such in your .m implementation:

```
- (NSArray *)graphView:(S7GraphView *)graphView yValuesForPlot:(NSUInteger)plotIndex
{
    if ( plotIndex == <some index value> )
        return redArray;
    else
        return nil;
}
```

I have no idea what `plotIndex` corresponds with your various color arrays, but you should get the idea.

When the `S7GraphView` object needs that data, it will invoke that `delegate` method.

This is not unlike implementing `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` methods. When a `UITableView` method `-reloadData` is invoked, it will call upon your view controller (presuming it is delegate/data source of the table) to supply `UITableViewCell` objects via

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = <... dequeue or created ... >.

    /* 
        do some cell set up code based on indexPath.section and indexPath.row
    */

    return cell;
}
```

Similar with `S7GraphView` I'm sure (I don't have the API to see all it does). In your `IBAction` method, you will probably be doing something like:

```
- (IBAction)histogram:(id)sender
{
    // maybe you recalculate your red, green, and blue component arrays here and cache
    // or maybe you calculate them when requested by the delegate method

    // tell the S7GraphView it needs to update
    // (not sure what the reload method is actually called)
    [self.myS7GraphView reloadGraph];
}
```